# Convert code of "AudioStreamPacketDescription" into swift3.2

Tags: swift3, audiotoolbox, audioqueueservices

I'm converting `Audio Queues Service` code into swift3.2 but i got stuck here.i don't know how to write this line of code in swift updated version.

I want to convert below code into swift 3.2

```
player.packetDescs = UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>(malloc(sizeof(AudioStreamPacketDescription) * Int(player.numPacketsToRead)))
```

where `player` object is :

```
 class Player {
        var playbackFile: AudioFileID? = nil
        var packetPosition: Int64 = 0
        var numPacketsToRead: UInt32 = 0
        var packetDescs: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>? = nil
        var isDone = false
    }
```

I tried this :

```
let j = MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: AudioStreamPacketDescription.self) * Int(player.numPacketsToRead)                
player.packetDescs = UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>(malloc(j))
```

But this give me error :

> Cannot invoke initializer for type
>   'UnsafeMutablePointer' with an argument
>   list of type '(UnsafeMutableRawPointer!)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok Try this

```
let sizeTmp = MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: AudioStreamPacketDescription.self) * Int(player.numPacketsToRead)
let tmpPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>.allocate(capacity: sizeTmp)
player.packetDescs = tmpPointer
```